# Which is more metallic: boron or silicon?

Tags: periodic-trends, carbon-family, boron-family

I read somewhere that boron is more metallic. Is it correct? If so, can you please elaborate?

The reason why I'm confused is because 2 factors come into play here:

1. When you move towards right, metallic character decreases.
2. When you move downwards, metallic character increases.

So, which one would win?
Are there any exception cases I should look out for?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! We have a site policy for [homework](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141/7448) questions which can also apply to self-study questions. Please edit your question to include your thoughts, where you got stuck, and let us know where you're finding difficulty so we may best help you.

Comment: It's either metallic or it isn't. "More metallic" makes no sense. Both are non-metals.

Comment: @IanBush, not *nonmetals* but semimetal, semiconductor or metalloid! See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid

Comment: Both Boron and Silicon in their standard forms at STP have a band gap.  As such. they are non-metals. As the link provided says "No widely accepted definition of a metalloid exists", as such I don't think it is a useful term. Semimetal, with a positive direct band gap but negative indirect one, is of some use but not relevant here.

Answer (score 1):

Since both are [metaloids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid), or semiconductors, look for the [criteria that define them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalloid#Criteria-based). In particular, electronegativity or ionization energy are important.